# Dingo api $response is undefined

Tags: laravel, laravel-authorization

Getting error

"message": "Undefined property: App\Http\Controllers\Api\ApiUserXYzController::$response"

```
return $this->response->collection($user_list, new ProjectTransformer())->setStatusCode(200);
```

I"m tring to transform the data but i'm getting $response is not defined. please guide

Comment: I think right one is return response()->json($data,200);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to include the helper trait that the docs tell you to `use` if you want the response builder at the property `response` on the controller.

[Dingo Wiki - Responses - Response Builder](https://github.com/dingo/api/wiki/Responses)

```
use Dingo\Api\Routing\Helpers;

class SomeController ....
{
    use Helpers;
    ...
}
```